# Empty pdf while scraping using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I'm facing an issue while attempting to print a PDF from a webpage using Selenium in Python. The webpage in question is
https://jamabandi.nic.in/land%20records/NakalRecord. I'm trying to select the first record from each drop-down and then click on the "Nakal" button to generate a PDF.

However, the resulting PDF is always empty, even though there is a table present on the webpage. I've tried both the manual print-to-PDF operation and automated printing using Selenium, but in both cases, the generated PDF is empty.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Set up preferences for printing to PDF
settings = {
    "recentDestinations": [{"id": "Save as PDF", "origin": "local", "account": ""}],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}
prefs = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
    'printing.print_to_file': True,
    'printing.print_to_file.path': '/Users/jatin/Downloads/output.pdf'  # Specify the desired output path
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

import urllib.request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Optional: Run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
try:
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
except ValueError:
    latest_chromedriver_version_url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"
    latest_chromedriver_version = urllib.request.urlopen(latest_chromedriver_version_url).read().decode('utf-8')
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(version=latest_chromedriver_version).install())

    
options = Options()
url='https://jamabandi.nic.in/land%20records/NakalRecord'
# options.add_argument('--headless') #optional.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(url)


dropdown_district = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddldname"]'))
dropdown_district.select_by_index(1)
# Select the tehsil dropdown element and choose the first option,we will loop here for multiple anchals
drop_down_tehsil = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddltname"]'))
drop_down_tehsil.select_by_index(1)
drop_down_vill = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlvname"]'))
drop_down_vill.select_by_index(1)
drop_down_year = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlPeriod"]'))
drop_down_year.select_by_index(1)
owner_names=Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListBox1"]'))
dropdown_locator = (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListBox1"]')
drop_down_owner = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlOwner"]'))
drop_down_owner.select_by_index(1)
owner_names =Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListBox1"]'))
owner_names.select_by_index(2)
page_source = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = page_source.find_all('table')
div_col_lg_12 = page_source.find('div', class_='col-lg-12')

# Find links within the selected div
links_within_div = div_col_lg_12.find_all('td')
links_within_div
# Perform actions on the links or retrieve their attributes
for link in links_within_div:
    k=link.find_all('a')
    if len(k)>0:
        new_link=(k[0]['href'])
        
javascript_code = str(new_link)

# Execute the JavaScript code
driver.execute_script(javascript_code)

window_handles=driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(window_handles[-1])

# Open the print dialog using JavaScript
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am looking into it, can you please tell what is your select function doing?

Comment: Is that website you're trying to access restricted to an IP region, by any chance?

Comment: No it is not restricted

Comment: @KaranGupta which select function are you talking about?

Comment: @jatinrajani I think it's restricted to Indian IP addresses. I tried to access the website using VPN from different places, didn't work.

Comment: @eternal_white But i think using vpn it should work.Because people from canada and us are able to access it

Comment: As I told you. I tried using my VPN and from different places (including Canada), it just doesn't work. Unfortunately my VPN doesn't support Indian IP addresses so I think I can't access it. If they're using some solution that dynamically stores IP addresses associated with VPNs, I'll be very curious about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generated PDF is empty because in the document, you have:

```
<style>
    @media print
    {
        html,body
        {
            display:none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

So the document content is hide from the print. What you need is to remove the `<script>` tag:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('style').remove()")
driver.execute_script("window.print()")
```

[image]

**Edit**:

To extract data directly from page source, you can use [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
import io

page_source = io.StringIO(driver.page_source)
df = pd.read_html(page_source, attrs={'id': 'GridView1'})[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    खेवट या जमाबंदी न.  खतौनी न.  ... माल और सवाई के ब्यौरे सहित मांग            अभियुक्ति
0                    7      10.0  ...                             NaN        बरूऎ रपट न. 1
1                   //       NaN  ...                             NaN  तिथी 26-09-2012 रजि
2                    7       NaN  ...                             NaN          न.4173 तिथी
3                  NaN       NaN  ...                             NaN   24/09/2012 4:27:00
4                  NaN       NaN  ...                             NaN     PM के अनुसार मिन
..                 ...       ...  ...                             ...                  ...
124                NaN       NaN  ...                             NaN                  NaN
125                NaN       NaN  ...                             NaN                  NaN
126                NaN       NaN  ...                             NaN                  NaN
127                NaN       NaN  ...                             NaN                  NaN
128                NaN       NaN  ...                             NaN                  NaN

[129 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: Hello, how did you access the URL? Every time I try to access it, it doesn't open. Is you IP from India? If that's the case, then it might be that the website is blocking any traffic from outside India..

Comment: I used an [open proxy](https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-in/) then with `selenium` I configured it with `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=...')`. And yes the traffic is blocked for all IP outside India. In any case, it doesn't work from France

Comment: Thanks a lot @Corralien it is working.But i am trying to save that pdf in order to parse it using pandas.But not able to save tried kiosk printing as well.

Comment: Why do you want to parse the PDF with Pandas? Wouldn't it be easier to retrieve the HTML content to make it a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you an example of HTML extraction.